# How to create the following JSON in jQuery

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create the following JSON, but it's not getting created as expected.

```
{
"fields":{
"summary":"Test-Summary1",
"description":"Test-Description1",
"igniteRCA":"IGNRCA1",
"igniteWhere":"IGNWHR1",
"igniteWhile":"IGNWHL1",
"igniteWhat":"IGNWHT1",
"igniteHow":"IGNHOW1",
"igniteBy":"IGNBY1"
}
}
```

Below is my code:

```
var data2 = {};
  var fields = {};
        var data4 = {};
        fields.summary = document.getElementById("title").value;
        fields.description = document.getElementById("problemDescription").value;
        fields.igniteRCA = document.getElementById("rcaClassification").value;
        fields.igniteWhere = document.getElementById("IGNITE_Where").value;
        fields.igniteWhile = document.getElementById("IGNITE_While").value;
        fields.igniteWhat = document.getElementById("IGNITE_What").value;
        fields.igniteHow = document.getElementById("IGNITE_How").value;
        fields.igniteBy = document.getElementById("IGNITE_By").value;
        data4.fields = fields;
        Object.assign(data2, data4);
```

And below is the output I got.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxIw0.png)

I am not able to create the `fields` object inside the empty object properly as I mentioned above.

As I am new to javascript and jQuery. Can someone please help me with the mistake I am doing with my code? I want to construct the exact JSON. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why involve jQuery in this at all?

Comment: Is there an error in your console? Is the output different? If so, what is the output and how is it not expected?

Comment: Please provide a [clear description of the problem](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/) and a [mcve]

Comment: Re edit: "And below is the output I got." — that looks right, what is the problem?

Comment: Re second edit: "I am not able to create the fields object inside the empty object properly as I mentioned above." — I can see the fields property with the object value in your screenshot!

Comment: Firstly, fields should be within empty curly braces, then the property inside fields should also be in curly braces. Please check the JSON I have written in beginning. Both don't match exactly.

Comment: @AnanyaOberoi — So your complaint is that the console's GUI for exploring objects doesn't use the same symbols to display the object that you expect?

Answer (score -1):

Are you simply trying to achieve something like this?

This isn't complete - just to get you going.

Maybe I've missed something?

```js
var data2 = {
  "fields": {
    "summary": document.getElementById("title").value,
    "description": document.getElementById("title").value,
    "igniteRCA": document.getElementById("title").value,
    "igniteWhere": document.getElementById("title").value,
    "igniteWhile": document.getElementById("title").value,
    "igniteWhat": document.getElementById("title").value,
    "igniteHow": document.getElementById("title").value,
    "igniteBy": document.getElementById("title").value
  }
}

console.log(data2);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input id="title" value="Some Title"/>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: They are achieving that (albeit through an overly complicated approach).

Comment: @Robin Webb, your output is correct, but when I am passing this data2 variable to the api, it's not passing as it is. It is like :
fields%5Bsummary%5D=Test-Summary&fields%5Bdescription%5D=Test-Description&fields%5BigniteRCA%5D=Idctestapp2&fields%5BigniteWhere%5D=Build%2FPackage&fields%5BigniteWhile%5D=Configuration+Validation&fields%5BigniteWhat%5D=&fields%5BigniteHow%5D=&fields%5BigniteBy%5D=Configuration+Compliance

Can this be corrected ?

Comment: How are you converting your object to a query string?